# Detect dynamic type in Dart

Tags: dart

Is there a way to detect the type `dynamic` in Dart?

I have the following method:

```
Stream<T> on<T>() {
  if (T is dynamic) { // <-- Is always true
    // Return the dynamic Stream.
  } else {
    // Return the Stream that was cast to Stream<T>.
  }
}
```

I would like to find out if the user called the method `on` with a type parameter or not. So, I'd like to differentiate between a call to `myClass.on()` and `myClass<MyType>.on()`.

Is this possible in Dart 2 and above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Dart 2, which you are using since you have a generic method, there is no way to distinguish the type `dynamic` and the type `Object` at run-time, because there is no difference.

The difference between `dynamic` and `Object` exists only at compile-time, where you are allowed to call any method on a value with static type `dynamic`, and not very many methods on something with static type `Object`. The difference affects compilation, but after compiling, the things you can do with a type are restricted to checking if an object is an instance of the type (all objects are instances of both `Object` and `dynamic`), or whether a type is a sub-type of another (`Object` and `dynamic` have the same sub-types and super-types, and are sub- and super-types of each other, they are completely equivalent wrt. sub-typing).

You test `if (T is dynamic)` is meaningless, it converts `T` to a `Type` object representing the type, and that type object is an object, and all objects are instance of (what `is` checks) `dynamic`.

You can try `if (new Object() is T)`, which only succeeds if T is a "top type", which includes `dynamic`, `Object` and `void`.
Or you can try `if (T == dynamic)` which should give the same result (if it doesn't, it's a bug that we'll fix - since `Object == dynamic` should be true).

All in all, you should not try to detect `dynamic` in Dart 2 because it's not actually special at run-time.

You cannot check whether the user passed a type parameter because type parameters are optional, and if the user don't add one, one will be supplied, computed by the bound of the type variable (which is `dynamic`/`Object` here).

Comment: Thanks, it's working with `T == dynamic`. I seemed to hit a bug when I was using Dart 2.0.0-dev.63 where my runtime type information was completely lost and the `is` check was not possible. Now with Dart 2.0.0-dev.67 it's all working fine again.

BTW: I'm using it in the [`event_bus`](https://github.com/marcojakob/dart-event-bus/) package. See [those lines of code](https://github.com/marcojakob/dart-event-bus/blob/v1.0.0/lib/event_bus.dart#L45-L53).

Hope this is how it is meant to be used in Dart 2.0. (glad if you could verify this...).

Comment: I'll just warn you that while `T == dynamic` works right now, it should be true too when `T` is `Object`, and when we fix the bug, it will be, so if you want to treat `dynamic` and `Object` differently, you will not be able to do so.

Comment: @lrn  IMHO `T == dynamic` would make sense so that you can do an assert in generic functions.  like `assert(T!= dynamic)`. I also think  `is of type` should be different from equality because `concreteType == dynamic`  should be false while   `concreteType is dynamic` should be true.

Comment: Can you please tell how I can know "whether a type is a sub-type of another"

Comment: Checking whether a type variable holds a type which is a subtype of another type is ... actually a little tricky. The trick I usually use is `<T>[] is List<S>` to check if `T` is a subtype of `S`. There is no direct way to check `T < S`.